# Can you left and right join in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need 3 tables that are all relevant to the same thing.

For instance, 1 has user information, 1 has page information for that user and the other has page options for that user.

all connected through user_id

is is possible to do this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN page_info ON users.id=page_info.user_id 
RIGHT JOIN page_settings ON user.id=page_settings.user_id 
WHERE users.id=$id
```

or will i be defeated to using 2 queries

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what a `LEFT` and `RIGHT` outer join do: read [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

In your case, with the `users` table coming first (i.e. to the "left" of all others), I suspect you want both joins to be `LEFT` outer joins?  That is:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users 
  LEFT JOIN page_info     ON users.id = page_info.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN page_settings ON users.id = page_settings.user_id 
WHERE  users.id = $id
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html